# Is pointer arithmetics on NULL defined

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Is pointer arithmetics on NULL defined?
Is below defined in C language?

```
void foo(void)
{
    int *a = NULL;
    a += 4;
    printf("%p\n", (void *)a);
}
```

or

```
void foo(void)
{
    int *a = NULL;
    int *v = a;
    printf("%td\n", v - a);
}
```

Comment: I.A.N.A.L.L. but despite what the spec says, your examples _will_ [always] work. Because you're _not_ dereferencing the pointer. The spec is substituting rules [for newbies] vs. an understanding of the architecture. 0 is chosen as the null pointer value but it could be (e.g.) 0xFFFFFFF in some impl. Note that, in a kernel, 0 could be _valid_ on some arches. They sometimes put something at 0: an interrupt vector table for example. So, `void *ivt = (void *) 0;` is valid. And, `ivt[0] = ivt_function_1; ivt[1] = ivt_function_2;` works. Here, UB means "it might work" or "does work".

Comment: Under Unix/Posix/Linux, in userspace, access to `NULL` causes a segfault. But, this is because the kernel sets the protection of page 0 to "no access" to trap these accesses as an aid to the programmer. On older systems, code was in page 0 [sometimes R/O], so writing 0 would fault. So, 99.44% of the time dereferencing 0 is bad juju. But, arithmetic on it won't set the cpu on fire--just usage of pointer.

Comment: @CraigEstey *I.A.N.A.L.L. but despite what the spec says, your examples will [always] work.*  Ooof.  You simply can not support that.  There is no way you can rule out an aggressive optimizing compiler doing something with that code to produce unexpected results.  "It's always worked for me and I can't see how it could fail" places no limits on future failure modes the rest of the universe can concoct.